# How to include if-else with computed variables in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

I am trying to plot some grids with each point circled in a certain color based on the coordinates. I find some code online to use ifthen package to include the if statement, the following code works if I color the diagonal point by condition "if \x=\y"

```
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}
  {
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\x=\y}{\def\col{red}}{\def\col{black}}
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill,color=\col] at (\x,\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But now I need to color the off-diagonal line, which should be conditioned on \x=\y+1, and if I change the \ifthenelse with condition

```
    \ifthenelse{\x=\y+1}{\def\col{red}}{\def\col{black}}
```

The plot is still color the diagonal element. I also try

```
    \ifthenelse{\x-\y=1}{\def\col{red}}{\def\col{black}}
```

Then only the origin will be red. It is quite confusing how to do the math on variables and make them work with \ifthenelse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in `ifthenelse` of pgf.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}
  {
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}
    {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{ifthenelse(\x==\y,"red",ifthenelse(\x==\y+1,"blue","black"))}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill,color=\col] at (\x,\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works. And it supports some math function like abs(\x-\y)<=1, cool!

Comment: @user1285419 Yes, pgf has **p**retty **g**ood **f**eatures. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

TikZ runs everything through `\pgfmathparse`, allowing one to use math expressions, but ifthen does not.  So `{\x=\y+1}` actually compares macros `\x` and `\y` and ignores the `+1` (since it still sets the main diagonal).

Also, I assume you don't want to reset the main diagonal to black.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,6}
  {
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}
    {
      \ifthenelse{\x=\y}{\def\col{red}}{\def\col{black}}
      \pgfmathparse{\y+1}
      \ifthenelse{\x=\pgfmathresult}{\def\col{blue}}{}
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill,color=\col] at (\x,\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks. That is something I miss. But I am thinking if I want to make it general, that is, automatically color any diagonal and off-diagonal line, for example, the main diagonal plus two closest off-diagonal lines, I try to modify it as \pgfmathparse{\x*\x - 2*\x*\y + \y*\y}
      \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult<2}{\def\col{blue}}{\def\col{black}} it does not seems to work, any idea?

Comment: Aha!  `\ifthenelse` only handles integers.  Use `\pgfmathparse{int(\x*\x - 2*\x*\y + \y*\y)}`